# CoroutineScope and GlobalScope differences in terms of lifecycle

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I understand that GlobalScope is tied an application lifecycle, so as long as the application is alife, but then, CoroutineScope doesn't seem to be tied to any lifecycle at all, so, if I launch a coroutine with either of them, what is the real difference? Seems that launching a coroutine with CoroutineScope isn't much different from doing it with GlobalScope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a `CoroutineScope`, you are expected to manage its lifecycle manually and cancel it if it is not needed anymore. This is how scopes created with `CoroutineScope` are meant to be used. So these scopes have a proper lifecycle, but only as long as you use them properly.

`GlobalScope` on the other hand is a special type of `CoroutineScope` which is expected to be active all the time. It doesn't have a lifecycle by design.

If you see someone replaces `GlobalScope.launch()` which something like `CoroutineScope().launch()`, then yes, you are correct - this is almost the same. People don't understand this, so they think they fixed the problem only because IDE doesn't show a warning anymore.